# why python shell is behaving like this?

Tags: python, shell

when i am trying to print the function from the python shell it is giving me output like this, which is correct.

```
>> simplify(~A | (C & (~(B & ~C) | A)))
>> ~A | C
```

I am trying to do the same thing in this manner using python file

```
res = simplify(~A | (C & (~(B & ~C) | A)))
print res
```

It is giving me this output.

```
| ~A
C
```

Comment: That doesn't look like any Python shell *I've* ever seen...

Comment: Python shell returns the `repr` version while `print` returns the `str` version.

Comment: Would you specify the Python library that you are using that implements the logic simplification you show?